# Passing arguments as const reference vs normal reference

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How come a non-const reference cannot bind to a temporary object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565600/how-come-a-non-const-reference-cannot-bind-to-a-temporary-object)

There is such code:

```
void fun_ref(int& par){}

void fun_const_ref(const int& par){}

int main(){

  //fun_ref(2); error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘int&’ from a temporary of type ‘int’
  fun_const_ref(2);

  char var = 3;
  //fun_ref(var); error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘int&’ from expression of type ‘char’
  fun_const_ref(var);
  return 0;
}
```

Why is it possible to pass rvalue and different data type than type of function parameter for constant reference, but it is not possible for non-constant reference?

Answer (score 3):

When the argument is a const reference and the argument passed is not of that type but there is an implicit conversion to that type, the implementation will hold the value in a temporary and use such temporary as argument. So the const version is not taking a reference to `char var` but to `int __temp`.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case, `2` is a temporary so it can only be bound to a `const` reference; that's why you cannot call `fun_ref` with it.

In the second case, `var` is a `char` so it cannot be bound to an `int&`. However, it is possible for `var` to be converted to a temporary `int`, which can be bound to a `const int&` as above; that one works due to the implicit coversion.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler can create a temporary of the function argument type by implicit conversion and pass it as a const reference. This does not work for a reference type, since temporaries cannot be passed as non-const references.

Edit: Non-const references to temporaries are disallowed because the standard says so. The reason behind this is that a function getting a non-const reference will change its argument (or else you could have made the reference const), and these changes will be lost when the temporary goes out of scope.

Comment: Right, that, and the question was *why* can't temporaries be passed as non-const references?